# Azure Devops dashboard stuck with previous iteration

Tags: azure-devops, dashboard

I am a standlone dev and create my iterations in AzureDevOps. Every 2-3 weeks I create new iteration. Dashboard was updating accordingly - all the elements on it are querying the current iteration. One day when the new iteration needed to start it continued to show the old one. After several days I created a new iteration setting the timeframe from the current day at the time, append some features and tasks to it but this didn't update the dashboard. Till today it stays with the old stuck iteration.
When I check the queries al lof them behave the same way:
- I choose explicitely the name of the iteration - the query returns the results
 - I choose the iteration as "@CurrentIteration" and the respective team and no results are shown. 
It behaves like the current iteration is not from the selected team. But the iteration is really from the list of iterations for the team.
Any advice and help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I found my mistake.
I was creating only the iteration through Project Settings ->Boards -> Project Configuration but was not assigning it to the team through Project Settings -> Boards-> Team Configuration. 
Now everything works fine again.

Comment: You shouldn't need to go into the project settings to create the iterations/sprints. You should setup your team to have access to a "home" iteration path that represents the backlog, then from the planning view on the backlog you can create sprints and drop work items into them.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. All I did was:

- logged out
- cleared all cache
- logged back in

It worked for me